# Creating list form in r

Tags: r

We have variables and when we append them they become character strings but we need list form for those.

1. we have `list (DOB, Age)` and `list (_Alpha, _Gamma, _Theta)` and `list (values)`

```
a1 <- c("DOB_Alpha=c(0.5,3)","DOB_Gamma=c(0.5,3)","DOB_Theta=c(0.5,3)","Age_Alpha=c(0.5,3)")
```

a1

[1] "DOB_Alpha=c(0.5,3)" "DOB_Gamma=c(0.5,3)"
[3] "DOB_Theta=c(0.5,3)" "Age_Alpha=c(0.5,3)"

```
b <- list(DOB_Alpha=c(0.5,3),DOB_Gamma=c(0.5,3))
```

b

$DOB_Alpha
[1] 0.5 3.0

$DOB_Gamma
[1] 0.5 3.0

how can I get output as b from a1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a1` is a character vector. Ideally, `a1` is already created as a list. To get the same output as `b` from `a1`, `a1` first has to be converted from a character vector to a list.

```
#create list to bind results to
result <- list()

#loop through elements of a1 to extract name and values, append to list
for(i in seq_along(a1)){
  #retrieve values of list
  list_values <- sapply(strsplit(a1[i], "=c"), `[`, 2) #retrieves values
  list_values <- gsub("\\)|\\(", "", list_values) #removes brackets
  list_values <- strsplit(list_values, ",") |> unlist() |> as.numeric() #strsplit based on commas, unlist and convert values to numeric
  
  #retrieve name of list
  list_name <- sapply(strsplit(a1[i], "=c"), `[`, 1)
  
  #append to list
  result[[list_name]] <- list_values
}

result
$DOB_Alpha
[1] 0.5 3.0

$DOB_Gamma
[1] 0.5 3.0

$DOB_Theta
[1] 0.5 3.0

$Age_Alpha
[1] 0.5 3.0
```